# Inspect NSCache contents on iOS?

Tags: ios, nscache

Is there a way to inspect NSCache's contents for debugging purposes?

This would not be used in the App Store. I just would like to be able to see what's going on in there while debugging. The `description` is pretty useless.

Comment: I don't know any existing tool which can help you doing that. But NSCache is thread-safe. You may just want to write a small daemon which stores the content of NSCache to disk based on a timer.

Comment: While you can pull objects out of a cache based on their key, there doesn't seem to be a way to enumerate or get all the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open-source replacement for NSCache that solves this exact issue: https://github.com/gregkrsak/GKCache

Comment: This is exactly the code I was about to write, so thanks for the link. :)

Answer (score 10):

No need to use a third party library. You can do this using the "allObjects" key from NSCache. For example:

```
if let all = yourCache.value(forKey: "allObjects") as? NSArray {
    for object in all {
        print("object is \(object)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NSCache doesn't have such feature. But you can use custom solution, e.g.: [VSCache](https://github.com/ViacheslavSoroka/VSCache)

It's thread-safe and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all keys and objects with

`-[NSCache mapTableRepresentation]`